# How to build a menu that change style over a section

Tags: menus

create this menu : https://goldkant.de/

this is not wordpress but i want to do it on WP.

exist a plug-in to help me that i ignore?

the most curious thing is that:
the menu is changing syle when it pass over a div and i really don't know how to do it

tnx

Comment: This is question related to HTML and not wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I found this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slide-anything/).  Not sure if that would help. Maybe do a google search with the words "plugin," "change image," and "scroll" in it.  I sometimes have greater success looking there than in the main wordpress plugin directory.

On another note, Javascript can change styles or images when passing over a div.  Here are a few instructional pages on w3schools to get you started on the kind of Javascript you are looking for.  However, I recommend starting from the beginning of the Javascript section of the site and learning straight through, but this will show you what it can do.  Viewing all three might give you a starting point to put this all together on your own.
[getting position of div on page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp),
[changing images with javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb), and
[changes made onmouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)